# multi level Recursive template

Tags: c++

I want to implement a recursive template：

```
template<unsigned int M,unsigned int N>
class Special:Special<M,N-1>
{
    void * get()
     {
           return (Special <M,N-1>*)this;
     }
}

template <>
class Special<0,0>
 { 
       void * get()
        {
               return this;
        }
 }

 void main()
 {
       Special<3,2> specialobj;
  }
```

How can I get specialobj which can contain all the base object(3*2) and each base object has a get function?

Comment: The base case / primary template with params <0,0> will never be pattern matched as you only decrement N

Comment: @LloydCrawley that is the part which beats me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need partially specialize your base-case template.

```
template<unsigned int M, unsigned int N>
class Special :Special<M, N - 1>
{
    void * get() { return (Special <M, N - 1>*)this; }
};

template <unsigned int M>
class Special<M, 0>
{
    void * get() { return this; }
};

void main()
{
    Special<3, 2> specialobj;
}
```

With new requirements from comment below the code would look like this:

```
template<unsigned int M, unsigned int N>
class Special : public Special<M, N - 1>
{
    auto get() { return this; }
};

template <unsigned int M>
class Special<M, 0> : public Special <M - 1, 2>
{
    void * get() { return this; }
};

template <>
class Special<0, 0>
{
    void * get() { return this; }
};
```

With another update it will look like this:

```
template<unsigned int NStart, unsigned int M, unsigned int N>
class SpecialInternal : public SpecialInternal<NStart, M, N - 1>
{
    auto get() { return this; }
};

template <unsigned int NStart, unsigned int M>
class SpecialInternal<NStart, M, 0> : public SpecialInternal <NStart, M - 1, NStart>
{
    auto get() { return this; }
};

template <unsigned int NStart>
class SpecialInternal<NStart, 0, 0>
{
    auto get() { return this; }
};

template<unsigned int M, unsigned int N>
class Special : public SpecialInternal<N, M, N>
{
    auto get() { return this; }
};
```

And finally test:

```
void main()
{
    Special<3, 2> specialobj;

    cout << std::boolalpha;
    cout << "<3,2>: " << is_base_of<SpecialInternal<2, 3, 2>, Special<3, 2>>::value << endl;
    cout << "<3,1>: " << is_base_of<SpecialInternal<2, 3, 1>, Special<3, 2>>::value << endl;
    cout << "<3,0>: " << is_base_of<SpecialInternal<2, 3, 0>, Special<3, 2>>::value << endl;
    cout << "<2,2>: " << is_base_of<SpecialInternal<2, 2, 2>, Special<3, 2>>::value << endl;
    cout << "<2,1>: " << is_base_of<SpecialInternal<2, 2, 1>, Special<3, 2>>::value << endl;
    cout << "<2,0>: " << is_base_of<SpecialInternal<2, 2, 0>, Special<3, 2>>::value << endl;
    cout << "<1,2>: " << is_base_of<SpecialInternal<2, 1, 2>, Special<3, 2>>::value << endl;
    cout << "<1,1>: " << is_base_of<SpecialInternal<2, 1, 1>, Special<3, 2>>::value << endl;
    cout << "<1,0>: " << is_base_of<SpecialInternal<2, 1, 0>, Special<3, 2>>::value << endl;
    cout << "<0,2>: " << is_base_of<SpecialInternal<2, 0, 2>, Special<3, 2>>::value << endl;
    cout << "<0,1>: " << is_base_of<SpecialInternal<2, 0, 1>, Special<3, 2>>::value << endl;
    cout << "<0,0>: " << is_base_of<SpecialInternal<2, 0, 0>, Special<3, 2>>::value << endl;
}
```

Output:

> <3,2>: true
>   <3,1>: true
>   <3,0>: true
>   <2,2>: true
>   <2,1>: true
>   <2,0>: true
>   <1,2>: true
>   <1,1>: true
>   <1,0>: true
>   <0,2>: true
>   <0,1>: true
>   <0,0>: true

Comment: I want M recursive to 0 , need 6 class: Special<3,2> <3,1> <3,0><2,2><2,1><2,0><1,2><1,1><1,0><0,2><0,1><0,0> ,your answer doesn’t seem to achieve this

Comment: Thanks! could this be more generic? If I want a Special<4,5>,seems like I need modify these code again.

Comment: Yes it could, for this end you need to pass into the template one more parameter which will store value (2 in this case). I will update my answer in few minutes.

Comment: @zhangxiaoguo now it looks like it is what you want.